# How do I override Git configuration options by command line parameters?

Tags: git, config

I want to override certain Git configuration options (in my case `http.proxy`) when calling a Git command directly by using command line parameters. Is this possible?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Yes, you can pass it with `-c`, like:

```
git -c http.proxy=someproxy clone https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

Comment: Quoting from https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/

`-c <name>=<value>`

    Pass a configuration parameter to the command. **The value given will override values from configuration files.** The `<name>` is expected in the same format as listed by git config (subkeys separated by dots).

Comment: Great, thanks! Looks like I haven't googled as thoroughly as I should have done.

Comment: I find this useful if I occasionally want to use a different editor with git; e.g. `git -c core.editor=gedit commit`

Comment: I don't suppose there is an environment variable that will do the same, for when git is being called by a script and so adding a `-c` parameter is not practical?

Comment: Is there a way to provide several `-c` options at once?

Comment: @MilesBHuff sure, just add `-c` multiple times, e.g. `git -c http.proxy=localhost:3128 -c http.useragent=test`.

Answer (score 11):

Note that there is a new feature regarding the ability to override (with the command `git -c`) a config:

You couldn't set a config to an empty string (`git -c http.proxy=` or any other `foo.bar=`), that is until [git 2.1.2](https://github.com/git/git/releases/tag/v2.1.2) (Sept 30th, 2014), and [commit a789ca7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a789ca70e7a5b02973b116d21674acd795238f99) [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster)

### config: teach "`git -c`" to recognize an empty string

> In a config file, you can do:

```
[foo]
bar
```

> to turn the "`foo.bar`" boolean flag on, and you can do:

```
[foo]
bar=
```

> to set "`foo.bar`" to the empty string.
>   However, git's "`-c`" parameter treats both:

```
git -c foo.bar
```

> and

```
git -c foo.bar=
```

> as the boolean flag, and there is no way to set a variable to the empty string.
>   This patch enables the latter form to do that.

Comment: When was `-c` added?

Comment: @OndraŽižka In Git 1.7.2, March 2010: https://github.com/git/git/commit/8b1fa778676ae94f7a6d4113fa90947b548154dd

Answer (score 4):

As documented in Git 2.23 (Q3 2019), but already available before that, another place where you can override Git configuration option is... **git aliases**!

See [commit 459842e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/459842e1c2777812130545dc52753c6f4d517e21), [commit 01991ce](https://github.com/git/git/commit/01991cee86a01bfb1dd13a7c73d1f793c0b718d3) (05 Jun 2019) by [Denton Liu (`Denton-L`)](https://github.com/Denton-L).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 71221f2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/71221f28ec3f887620f0089b8f42bcf9b19f4a42), 09 Jul 2019)</sup>

> ### `config/alias.txt`: document alias accepting non-command first word
>
> One can see that an alias that begins with a non-command first word, such as `loud-rebase = -c commit.verbose=true rebase`, is permitted.
>   However, this isn't immediately obvious to users as alias instances typically begin with a command.
>
> Document the fact that an alias can begin with a non-command first word so that users will be able to discover that this is a feature.

[The documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/459842e1c2777812130545dc52753c6f4d517e21/Documentation/config/alias.txt#L10-L18) now includes:

> Note that the first word of an alias does not necessarily have to be a
>   command. **It can be a command-line option that will be passed into the
>   invocation of `git`**.
>
> In particular, this is useful when used with `-c` to pass in one-time configurations or `-p` to force pagination.
>
> For example, `loud-rebase = -c commit.verbose=true rebase` can be defined such that
>   running `git loud-rebase` would be equivalent to `git -c commit.verbose=true rebase`.
>
> Also, `ps = -p status` would be a helpful alias since `git ps` would paginate the output of `git status` where the original command does not.

For example, I defined:

```
vonc@vonvb:~/gits/src/git$ git config alias.loud-commit "-c commit.verbose=true commit"
vonc@vonvb:~/gits/src/git$ git loud-commit -a
```

That gives me:

[image: git loud commit]

The **diff** (red part) would *not* be present in a commit message editor with a simple `git commit -a`.

The alias did not need to start with `!git` to call the shell command `git`.
It can directly start with a `git` command option, like `-c`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.
At first how git stores his configuration?
I have working repo localy

```
cat ./projects/autoopt.ru/.git/config
```

[image]

So git stores settings in file. You may edit this file directly, but git provides CLI to simplify editing config params.

So what is command? May be git config set= Hmm... I need param name url? set url= not working?

So how to find out format of git config command?

- Open google, yandex in my case
- "git config spec"
- [Official git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)
- git config name [value [value-pattern]] (it means you need to pass name of property and space separated value

Now i need to find out how to write name of param when i need to change my remote repos url by given config file content.

```
[remote "origin"]
   url=...
```

Class remote, instance origin, class member url with value.

So answer is

```
git config remote.origin.url <value>
```