# How to make 'git log' decorate by default

Tags: git, git-log

I frequently type `git log` when what I actually want is `git log --decorate`. How do I make it decorate by default?

I have seen lots of answers of the form "make an alias *lg* and then type `git lg` instead of git log". But, I can't find anywhere how to change the default behaviour of `git log` itself. `alias log` does not work.

Comment: Git does not allow aliases to shadow existing commands, so you cannot create an alias called `log`.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`git config log.decorate auto`

For a global setting, add the  `--global` parameter.

So it would be:

```
git config --global log.decorate auto
```

The aliases are made with `git config alias.lg "log --decorate"`

Answer (score 23):

Update April 2017, 3 years later:

The correct syntax to use (as also mentioned in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21607489/6309)) is:

`git config --global log.decorate auto`

With Git 2.13 (Q2 2017), no need for configuration: `--decorate` is the default!

See [commit 940a911](https://github.com/git/git/commit/940a911f8ec00e291a66c2d1ed05293a38ae6138) (24 Mar 2017) by [Alex Henrie (`alexhenrie`)](https://github.com/alexhenrie).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d9758cf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d9758cf81cd8af42a7ab55dc3c1a889d9ddd3f81), 11 Apr 2017)</sup>

> The default behaviour of "`git log`" in an interactive session has
> been changed to enable "`--decorate`".

That means you would need to [override that option on command line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15884180/6309), to get back to the old behavior (for just one `log` execution):

`git -c log.decorate=false log`

---

Original answer (mid 2014)

Note: since git 2.1.0-rc0 (July 2014), Linus Torvalds himself introduced a `decorate=auto` option.
That is more precise than just `decorate=true`, especially for scripting purpose, as explained below.

See [commit 1571586](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1571586648da4e2d759bce1146d5585c91aca8d6) by [Linus Torvalds (torvalds)](https://github.com/torvalds):

> This works kind of like "`--color=auto`" - **add decorations for interactive use, but do not change defaults when scripting or when piping the output to anything but a terminal**.
>
> You can use either
>
> ```
> [log]
>      decorate=auto
> ```
>
> in the git config files, or the "`--decorate=auto`" command line option to choose this behavior.