# how do i make git log --graph the default

Tags: git, version-control

very similar to this question: [How to make git log decorate by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607305/how-to-make-git-log-decorate-by-default)

I would like to make `git log` do `git log --graph`. I assumed I could add something like `graph = true` to the `[log]` section of my `~/.gitconfig` file, but it did not work, nor did any of the other 28 things I tried putting into the `[log]` section. :(

I expect it will be suggested that I add an alias like `git lg`. I do not want to create an alias. I have two reasons for this:

1. my fingers have been typing `git log` for over a decade and I have no interest in changing that
2. As a result of my career, I am extremely conservative with my usage of aliases. I cannot add, nor am I always able to add, my alias to however many thousands of machines I end up interacting with as a cloud engineer. I use git on multiple machines and I want `git log` to be the solitary command I use to display the git log.

UPDATE: I thought of a way to do it, but I hate it. The idea is to create a bash script called `git` and put it somewhere in my path before `/usr/bin/git`. All it would do is call `/usr/bin/git` with whatever arguments are passed, unless it is a `log` in which case it will do the same but tack on a `--graph`. /me shudders

Comment: Note: if you want a *regular* `git log` (without the `--graph` added automatically), you can on demand add a `--no-graph` option to your `git log`, with Git 2.26 (Q1 2022). See [my edited answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43555332/6309).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2017: I don't know of:

- a git configuration for the graph option: you might have to propose a similar default behavior as the one I mentioned with [Git 2.13 for got log --decorate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25097285/6309)
- a way without wrapper of some sort

For instance, you can [define a bash function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16410521/6309) which would add the option

```
function do_git {
  cmd=$1
  shift
  extra=""
  if [ "$cmd" == "log" ]; then
    extra="--graph"
  fi
  "`which git`" "$cmd" "$extra" "$@"
}
```

Then add a wrapper or an alias to reference do_git.

The advantage is that the function is part of your dotfiles, that you can manage as a git repo and replicate across your machines. See for instance "
[Managing Dotfiles with Git](https://www.edwardthomson.com/blog/managing_dotfiles_with_git.html)"

2022: Note, a `log.graph` option is being [discussed/implemented](https://public-inbox.org/git/20220211163627.598166-3-alexhenrie24@gmail.com/T/#u).

---

But: what happens when you type `git log --graph` (resulting in `git log --graph --graph`)?

Or what if you want a regular `git log`? (*without* the --graph added automatically)

Before Git 2.36 (Q2 2022), "[`git log --graph --graph`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8813596531c08ed7488f85805cd0ec974a9c7c96/Documentation/rev-list-options.txt#L1127)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---graph))</sup> used to leak a graph structure, and there was no way to countermand "`--graph`" that appear earlier on the command line.

**A "`--no-graph`" option has been added and resource leakage has been plugged**.

See [commit 087c745](https://github.com/git/git/commit/087c745833be1edd3b3e4d8ea5d8b1a09fc6c245), [commit dccf6c1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dccf6c16f1cee485f05ef42ba67a9309c358a78d) (11 Feb 2022) by [Alex Henrie (`alexhenrie`)](https://github.com/alexhenrie).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8813596](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8813596531c08ed7488f85805cd0ec974a9c7c96), 23 Feb 2022)</sup>

> ### [`log`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/087c745833be1edd3b3e4d8ea5d8b1a09fc6c245): add a `--no-graph` option
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Alex Henrie</sup>

> It's useful to be able to countermand a previous `--graph` option, for example if [`git log --graph`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/087c745833be1edd3b3e4d8ea5d8b1a09fc6c245/Documentation/rev-list-options.txt#L1119)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---graph))</sup> is **run via an alias**.

Comment: You think as i do! Also, from further reading it appears git itself doesn't allow you to set graph in gitconfig. So wrapper it is, for now.

Comment: @tr3buchet Yes, for now there is no native option allowing to define that --graph as a default.

Comment: If you're going to wrap something, why not wrap `git-log`, as it will be more specific.  Also, you can create an alias in your `~/.gitconfig`, which seems like the best option.

Comment: @iconoclast an alias for git log? I believed it would not work: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5916565/6309, https://stackoverflow.com/a/3538791/6309. I did not try to define a `git-log` executable though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that doing it as default would be what you want in all cases anyway. I am thinking especially of cases when you will want to process the output of `git log` or when you add other options that would conflict with `--graph`.

So I prefer to go with the idea in your UPDATE and put a little script in my `$HOME/bin`, called `git` and which comes before the installed `git` in my `$PATH`.

It looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

function run_git(){
    real_git=$(which -a git | sed '2 !d;')
    bash -c "$real_git $(printf ' %q' "$@")"
}

if [ -t 1 ]; then
    case "$*" in
    log)
        run_git log --graph
        exit $?
        ;;
    esac
fi

run_git "$@"
```

The function:

- gets the actual `git` executable to call.
- runs the command, preserving spaces in argument by double-quoting them (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50367671/4117760)

The `[ -t 1 ]` test checks that this outputs directly to a terminal, to avoid messing potential scripts/programs/pipes up. (thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911168/how-to-detect-if-my-shell-script-is-running-through-a-pipe))

Then the `case` statement will allow to handle other similar cases simply.

Comment: Interesting addition to my own answer. +1. That script seems more complete than mine ;)

Comment: Doing it by default is exactly what I would want. For times that I don't want it (such as processing via script), I would expect one of two behaviors that other tools use. Either: a) git could detect that its output is going through a pipe and turn off default options that affect the display. Users could still manually specify these options. or better yet b) git should have a --graph as well as a --no-graph option. The latter could be used to turn off a default option. Both of these techniques are rather common in large CLI applications like VCS and package managers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `log --graph`by default, add to your `~/.bashrc` (or `~/bash_aliases`) this function:

```
function git {
  cmd=$1
  shift
  extra=
  if [ "$cmd" = "log" ]; then extra=--graph; fi
  "$(which git)" "$cmd" $extra "$@"
}
```

Now to get a possibility to see log without graph, and add a corresponding git alias:

```
 git config --global alias.log-default 'log'
```

If you have set up a non-default pretty format, and want to get rid of it, just add `--pretty=medium`

```
 git config --global alias.log-default 'log --pretty=medium'
```

Alternatively to git alias, you can add this line to the function git:

```
  if [ "$cmd" = "log-default" ]; then cmd='log'; extra=; fi
```