# git log command doesnt show HEAD info

Tags: git, git-log

I am creating a git repository and adding a file to the repository using `git commit`.
After commit in the `git log`, I could see the commit info but i am not able to see the `HEAD`info. Following is the steps that I followed:

```
$ git config --global user.name "abc"
$ git config --global user.mail "abc@abc.com"
$ git init
  Initialized empty Git repository in /home/aishwarya/github.com/temp/.git/
$ touch a.txt
$ git add a.txt

$ git commit --message "first commit in NonBareRepo"
  [master (root-commit) 6d46130] first commit in NonBareRepo
   1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
   create mode 100644 a.txt
$ git log
  commit 6d46130416eef0104408d575d8d4958457fe1dab
  Author: abc <abc@abc.com>
  Date:   Mon Feb 3 22:07:18 2020 +0530

      first commit in NonBareRepo
```

On other machine, after creating repository with the same steps, I could see the git log output as follows(HEAD points to master):

```
$ git log
commit 7ba4781ddee49a3636ee700fe057c3a372502460 (HEAD -> master)
Author: abc <abc@abc.com>
Date:   Mon Feb 3 22:01:11 2020 +0530

    first commit in NonBareRepo
```

Please let me know if I am missing something. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might have different config entries here. See [`log.decorate`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-logdecorate)

But anyway, to *explicitly* mention branch/tag info after the commit hash in log output, use the flags

```
# to force it
git log --decorate

# to prevent it
git log --no-decorate
```

As torek points out in comment [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60060533/git-log-command-doesnt-show-head-info/60060624?noredirect=1#comment106223392_60060624), the threshold is more precisely `1.7.2` version, where `log.decorate` appeared altogether. Before that point, there were no decorations at all, and since then it defaults to `auto` (meaning it's turned on by default).

Comment: Is it possible that different versions of git have this turned on by default / not ?

Comment: (I mean, I have it turned on but I don't see it in any of the `.config` files :) )

Comment: AFAIK, this is assumed `true` if not present. Did you try to `git config -l` from the machine where it doesn't show up? To spot a `log.decorate false` maybe?

Comment: I am not the OP, but I was wondering the same - maybe the OP can spot it by using this command.

Comment: `log.decorate` defaults to `auto` (or `true`? or something...) in Git versions 1.7.2 and later. If your machine on which you're *not* seeing it has Git 1.7.1 or earlier, you don't have `log.decorate` at all. (Edit: actually, I'm not sure if it was "auto" back then. There's a commit from Git 2.13 to fix a bug in the default "auto" mode as of 2.13, but when it became "auto" is less clear.)

Comment: @RomainValeri, @torek thank you for your kind reply. As @RomainValeri  suggested I could get the head pointer using `--decorate` option. @torek , I am using 2.7.4 and thus I think `--decorate` option should have been enabled by default. I however enabled it by using `git config --global log.decorate auto` as mentioned in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607305/how-to-make-git-log-decorate-by-default . I am now able to see the HEAD pointer. Thank you again.

Comment: Perhaps the OP is using mingw64 (git version 2.8.3.windows.1 like I am where the problem persists). There is no log.decorate file but --decorate works. Edit: if you are experiencing OP's problem, update Git for Windows. Works fine now.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @AndJM, it indeed works well now on recent enough mingw64 versions.