# Why won't Git override my merge.ff setting from the command line?

Tags: git, configuration, merge, command-line-arguments

I've set `merge.ff` to `only` in my local Git config:

```
$ git config --list | grep merge
merge.ff=only
```

This successfully prevents Git from performing a non-fast-forward merge, as expected.

However, when I want to explicitly allow such a merge and try to override that setting from the command line (either directly or as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15884261/647939)), I can't:

```
$ git merge --no-ff other-branch
fatal: You cannot combine --no-ff with --ff-only.
$ git -c merge.ff=false merge other-branch
fatal: You cannot combine --no-ff with --ff-only.
$ git -c merge.ff=true merge other-branch
fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: In case it's relevant, this is happening with Git 1.7.9.5.

Comment: Did you try `git merge --no-ff other-branch`?

Comment: Thanks - I had tried that, but had forgotten to include it in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I probably found the solution of that problem. According to the [release-notes of git 1.8.4](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0d8beaa5b76e824c9869f0d1f1b19ec7acf4982f/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.4.txt) the cli was not working correctly:

```
* The configuration variable "merge.ff" was cleary a tri-state to
  choose one from "favor fast-forward when possible", "always create
  a merge even when the history could fast-forward" and "do not
  create any merge, only update when the history fast-forwards", but
  the command line parser did not implement the usual convention of
  "last one wins, and command line overrides the configuration"
  correctly.
```

Comment: Good find.  On the back of this, dug into Git sources and can confirm that this commit[1] merges two ff-related variables into a single "always/never/optionally fast-forward" setting, and first appeared in 1.8.4.  Later, this commit[2] fixed the test description, which now clearly refers to exactly the issue I was having.  Accepted!

[1] https://github.com/git/git/commit/a54841e96b78203598dea6b31b9618f40f107e7b

[2] https://github.com/git/git/commit/6d2d43dc9d98ffc385066fbb46c587b6426bf0ac