# How to set a git config variable to the empty value from the command line

Tags: git, proxy

I am inside a corporate network that requires a proxy to be set up to access servers outside the intranet.

So, to be able to `git clone` from, say, github we have set up the `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable. That works fine.

However, we also have an internal git server. To properly access that we must *not* use the proxy. It works if I set this up in the `.gitconfig` file:

```
[http "http://stash.fabricam.com/"]
    proxy =
```

Since the proxy is set to the empty value here, no proxy is used for `git clone` from the server in question.

However, I would like to be able to create this configuration in a script, using `git config --global`. But I can't figure out how to do it.

These do not work

```
git config --global http.http://stash.fabricam.com/ ""
git config --global http.http%3A%2F%2Fstash.fabricam.com%2F ""
git config --global http.http%3A%2F%2Fstash.fabricam.com%2F ''
git config --global --add http.http%3A%2F%2Fstash.fabricam.com%2F
```

As you can see I have tried to use the [percent encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172719/escape-character-in-git-proxy-password/6172831#6172831), but that does not help.

I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884180/how-to-override-git-config-options-by-command-line-parameters), but I don't want to set this on every command, I really want to modify the `.gitconfig` file.

I have attempted setting up the `no_proxy` environment variable, but `git` does not seem to notice it.

I am in a Windows environment, running git 2.7.1

**edit**

Thanks to @choroba I got a bit further.

The behavior of this command is different depending on the shell:

```
git config --global http."http://stash.fabricam.com/".proxy ''
```

- In `PowerShell`, this does nothing at all.
- In `cmd.exe`

it creates this setting

```
[http "http://stash.fabricam.com/"]
    proxy = ''
```

But *that does not work*. The empty string is not the same as no string at all. It will result in this behavior:

```
> git clone http://stash.fabricam.com/test.git
Cloning into 'test'...
fatal: unable to access 'http://stash.fabricam.com/test.git/':
 Couldn't resolve proxy ''''
```

- In `bash` (that comes with git on windows) the command *does* work, and sets up the correct empty value. But I'd rather not script in bash when on windows, so this is not a good solution for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to include the `.proxy` key:

```
git config --global http."http://stash.fabricam.com/".proxy ''
```

In PowerShell, the empty string can be specified using backquotes:

```
`"`"
```

Comment: Good suggestion. Weirdly, I get no error when I execute that command, but it does not seem to do anything.
When I use a non-empty string, it works to set it to that string. But empty string does not work. I think that might be the syntax for un-setting a config setting.

Comment: @KlasMellbourn: Works for me, git 2.7.0 in cygwin.

Comment: Ok, I use Powershell by default. Discovery: It does nothing in powershell. In cmd.exe it sets proxy to ''. In bash (that comes with git) it is correctly set to nothing.

Comment: @KlasMellbourn: OK, how do you specify an empty argument in PowerShell?

Comment: Don't know really. It is sort of a hybrid world, using the unix-like git command in PowerShell.

Comment: @KlasMellbourn: Have you tried `""` instead of `''`?

Comment: Yes. Both behave the same in PowerShell, namely, do nothing.

Comment: Yes! That did it. This works in PowerShell: `git config --global http."http://stash.fabricam.com/".proxy \`"\`"`. Maybe you should add it to your answer, for clarity.