# Filename too long in Git for Windows when git clone is aborted in the middle

Tags: windows, git, filenames, long-filenames

I have a problem *similar* to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575662/filename-too-long-in-git-for-windows) **BUT** this is not a duplicate since the problem is different.

In that question, there was the problem of filenames too long for windows. The answer provided was to apply `git config core.longpaths true`

My own personal problem is that I have started cloning a repository. *In the middle of * clonning it stopped due to the filename too large error.

I tried

```
git config --system core.longpaths true

error: could not lock config file C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig: Permission denied
```

In the answer it says that it is better to not apply this globally so I did

```
git config core.longpaths true
fatal: not in a git directory
```

Ok I cd into the folder with the repo and I did the above and no problem. It is set.
But an interrupted clone can not be continued so if I erase the folder the config set would dissapear too right?

So how can I do the git clonning without this problem?

Comment: Nearly never, you change `--system` git config. You should set your user config with `--global`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set it temporarily with `--global`, and then unset it when the repo is cloned, and then set it locally to the repo?

You can also initialize an empty repository, set the thing locally, add a remote and finally fetch that remote, something like:

```
$ mkdir my_repo
$ cd my_repo
$ git init
$ git config core.longpaths true
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/repo/whatever.git
$ git fetch origin
```

Comment: [`-c` can be used to set config options for a single command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884180/how-do-i-override-git-configuration-options-by-command-line-parameters), so `git -c core.longpaths=true clone ...` should work. You'd probably still want to set that configuration in the newly created repository after that, though.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Didn't know that, thanks for the information. Then the flow would be: `git clone -c core.longpaths=true ...`, followed by `cd repo` and finally adding the config locally: `git config core.longpaths true`.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Seems like it can go both places and have since git-1.7.7 https://github.com/git/git/commit/84054f79de35015fc92f73ec4780102dd820e452

Comment: Interesting! I only tried it with `git status` because I didn't want to clone something to test his, but it makes sense to explicitly add that to clone. In fact I assume the ability in clone predates the more general one which applies to all commands, since for clone there's more need.

Comment: It came a bit before, possible for git-1.7.2: https://github.com/git/git/commit/8b1fa778676ae94f7a6d4113fa90947b548154dd